# Permission issues after system restore

Tags: windows-7

My Windows 7 x64 computer wouldn't boot this morning (I have since realized that it is because of an AVG Antivirus update from last night: http://product-team.blog.avg.com/2010/12/avg-fix-for-computers-running-on-windows-7-64-bit-platform.html)

Windows attempted to do a 'Startup Repair', but it failed. In reviewing the log of that attempt, I noticed that it had the system path as D:\Windows. It should be C:\Windows. There has never been a D drive!

So I performed a system restore and the computer now boots but it seems to have serious permission problems (I restored to various restore points with the same results). The following are some of the issues I'm seeing - they all seem to point to permissions to me.

I tried to open a command prompt and it says, "Windows cannot find 'cmd'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again." So I went looking for cmd.exe - I navigated to c:\windows and it says, "You don't currently have permission to access this folder. Click continue to permanently get access to this folder." I clicked continue and can now open cmd.exe.

I get that "You don't currently have permission..." message on many folders including c:\users\.

Windows won't save my changes to folder options.

If I am able to launch a program and I click 'pin this program to the start menu' nothing happens.

I get the same issues on newly created users even if they are administrators!

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? - http://www.windowsreference.com/security/reset-the-entire-registry-permissions-to-defaults/

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, Windows would create a virtual disk running in memory containing all of the repair tools and which became the C: drive for the duration of the repair, the original disk is then mounted as D: which is why (if this is still valid for Windows 7) your log shows Windows on the D: drive. As for the permissions, I can only guess that they would have been changed as part of the repair process which then remained set after the process failed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enter the command line in the System Restore menu? If so, find icacls in the restore drive, and run it.
Some simplistic syntax [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls)

If all else fail, you would need to boot using some linux live CD, copy the data to FAT/FAT32 drives, then reformat your whole drive.